# Does rhythm create pitch?

Tags: rhythm, pitch, harmonics, overtones, polyrhythm

> You see, rhythm and pitch are exactly the same thing, only at very
> different speeds.
> https://dantepfer.com/blog/?p=277

> Every pitch can be interpreted as a (very fast) rhythm, but the only
> rhythms that can be seen as pitches are continuous even pulses.
> https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/1tg8mm/the_connection_between_pitch_and_rhythm/

**Can someone explain this concept to me and how it can be related to music composition.**

> Edit: here’s a source with tons of examples of the type of answers I was looking for…
> https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.234339

Comment: It's a physics question, or a philosophy one. A percussion that repeats 440 times a second becomes a concert A, but by that time it can no longer be perceived as 'percussion'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a music question

Comment: I'm also voting to close this question since it's completely off-topic.

Comment: @ElEctric off topic from what

Comment: It's a language question, actually. People have used the word "rhythm" to refer to divisions of time large enough for humans to perceive and organize. While it's true that you could slow down a soundwave to the point that it becomes perceived as separate beats, or vice versa, that's largely a function of modern technology. To refer to an audible frequency as "rhythm," or to a recurring percussive beat as "pitch," is simply to use those words in ways they aren't normally used.

Comment: I'm voting to close simply because I can't find the specific question here; it's a bit too open-ended. Can you edit, either because the linked blog isn't making sense and you can specify the problem, or to ask a question building on it, more pointedly than "how does this relate to music composition"; that's more of a discussion prompt.

Comment: I was working on an answer as this was closed.  In brief, pitch and rhythm are both periodic sound phenomena but they are not the same. The periods are different by orders of magnitude. Rhythm can have pulses of irregular length (e.g. 3+3+2), which makes it a different rhythm. Such a change in a sound wave changes the timbre (so it is still the same pitch) or gives the perception of two pitches.  There are similarities, but the differences are greater.

Answer (score 2):

Extremely fast rhythms can indeed create pitch. The electronic music sub-genre of **extratone** involves music at 1000 BPM or faster - that's over 16 Hz! - so fast that the kick drum rhythm alone starts sounding like a musical note with an actual steady pitch.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with explaining where does it come from. A waveform repeating with period T can be represented as a sum of a sine wave with frequency f1 = 1/T, and its harmonics f2 = 2/T, f3 = 3/T... This is pure maths, Fourier analysis, to be specific.

So indeed, if you take any repeating rhythmic pattern, and you speed it up, either by squeezing its recorded waveform, or by speeding up MIDI, so that it repeats with e.g. 10ms period, it will produce a sound of base frequency of 1/10ms = 100 Hz. The harmonics actually may dominate over the base frequency, but this is the basic idea. It is demonstrated with examples in the articles you linked.

> rhythm and pitch are exactly the same thing, only at very different speeds

Such statement ignores that hearing is a psycho-acoustic phenomenon (rather than maths or pure physics one). The low limit of the human hearing frequency range is somewhere around 20 Hz. The rhythmic pattern below 20 Hz, that is longer than 50ms, won't be perceived as a sound with a recognizable pitch, but separate sounds. You won't be able to tune a guitar to the metronome, neither a composition will sound out of tune if played a bit faster, or slower.

Comment: The "beating" created by two pitches that are very close to each other can be heard as a rhythm. Right? That's where the rhythm and pitch frequency ranges kind of co-exist. Maybe the phenomenon could be used in electronic music composition.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica ah yes, beating could work!

Answer (score 0):

It may semantically have some truth in it, but as far as the actual concept is concerned, it's practically (in reality) impossible. If it did relate to certain pitches, then playing a tune in a different key wouldn't work - the 'rhythms' wouldn't be appropriate, so it wouldn't sound as good in one key as in another.

There are folks who would perhaps use this argument to back up why a particular song has to be in a particular key, but I'm totally sceptical about that. Many other, better reasons exist for that.

Dvers - reasons, please!

Comment: "playing a tune in another key wouldn't work": why not?  A given rhythm retains its identity at a different tempo, doesn't it?

Comment: @phoog - that was my point, really, but from the opposite direction.